# Mura 7.1 Translation Plugin not appearing on site

Tags: mura

I am not able to see the plugin that is provided by Mura on my website.

Roll over to Mura 7.0 was done to our external website. I am currently working on Vietnamese Website and would like to add the translation plugin that I did in Mura 6. In Mura 6, we were provided an id of the plugin which you would all to render the plugin. Here is an example on what I normally did in Mura 6: `#renderer.dspObject('plugin','4F5C1CC6-144D-0102-11E1F890D5A1A0FD')#`. However, in Mura 7, such id is not provided. Instead the following is what is provided: `#m.dspObject(object='muratranslationstools')#`. Where can I find the plugin id that was provided in Mura 6 in Mura 7?

In Mura 6, I did the following which works fine:`#renderer.dspObject('plugin','4F5C1CC6-144D-0102-11E1F890D5A1A0FD')#`

However, in Mura 7, I am giving the following: `#m.dspObject(object='muratranslationstools')#`

I have tried putting the #m.dspObject(.... in the render tag, without the render tag and it still does not appear.

The expected result is it will show a dropdown of the available languages of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. To resolve the issue, I did the following:

```
#m.setDynamicContent(m.dspObject(object='muratranslationsnavtools'))#
```

I hope it helps anyone else who encounters the same problem.

UPDATE: Although the above code will show the plugin, in some instances, will show the dropdown as a list. To avoid this, you can try the following approach as well:

```
#m.dspObject(
              object="muratranslationsnavtools",
              objectparams={muratranslationstooltype='selectbox'}
        )#
```

Hope this helps anyone who encounters the same problem